# Spring Boot not starting after upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have just upgraded from Spring Boot 1.5.19 to 2.3.11 and upgraded from Gradle 4.0 to 6.5

I can get the projects to build, but when I try and run I get the following error.

This was running fine before the upgrade.

```
*****************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
*****************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in controllers.IndexController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl' that could not be found.
```

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide ! Hi & Welcome! (it is not *that* simple ...and "can get the projects to build" means: the tests are bad! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how this bean was wired before into your application. I would say that this is definitely not the problem of Gradle update that now this bean is missing.

You should make sure [following dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail/2.5.0) is included in your project

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail', version: '2.5.0'
```

And verify that configuration is [properly set up](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email).